# Default value of var in Swift 3

Tags: swift, string, struct

In my struct, I declare vars as:

```
public var name:String?
public var X:String?
public var Y:String?
```

Now my problem is if someone accesses .name of struct, if it is not set I need to return X+Y, provided both X & Y are set, else I need to return "dummy". How do I achieve this?

Comment: What you're asking sounds more like a computed property...not a stored property

Comment: Well it's a stored property. In case no one renames it using text editor the default value is X+Y.

Comment: hmmm all case are 1. name 2. X+Y 3. dummy right?

Comment: Those properties are declared as `var` - if someone changes the value of X or Y would you expect the value of `name` to change as well - or is the value of name fixed forever the first time you ask for it?

Comment: No if someone explicitly changes name, then the value is the stored value of name, but if the value is not entered via text field input it will be X+Y with a fallback option "dummy"

Comment: @Cruz yes you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work

```
struct Struct {
    private var _name: String?
    var name: String? {
        get {
            if let name = _name {
                return name
            } else if let x = X, let y = Y {
                return x + y
            } else {
                return "dummy"
            }
        }

        set(newValue){
            _name = newValue
        }
    }

    var X: String?
    var Y: String?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a computed property like this:

```
struct S
{
    private var _name:String?
    public var X:String?
    public var Y:String?

    public var name:String
    {
        if let name:String = self._name
        {
            return name
        }
        else if let x:String = self.X, let y:String = self.Y
        {
            return x + y
        }
        else
        {
            return "dummy"
        }
    }
}
```

To set `name`, add a Swift [property setter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).

```
    public var name:String
    {
        get
        {
            ...
        }
        set(new_value)
        {
            self._name = new_value
        }
    }
```

However, this will not allow you to set the name back to `nil`. For that, you need to define a dedicated setter method in your struct.

Comment: And how do you **set** `name`?

Comment: @vadian use a [swift property setter](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html).

Comment: `if let name:String` <-- you don't need the `:String` nor you need it for `if let x:String` or `if let y:String`

Comment: No, it's not that easy. Using this syntax `name` is get-only and you need some logic to update `_name`

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea. Indeed if I were to do that, I could include a func called defaultname, like how I do in ObjectiveC. There should be something clean in Swift, if not then I am surprised.

Comment: @vadian name is get-only because the `set()` submethod was not included. Adding it is simple.

Comment: @Honey always better to be explicit about types; it cuts down compile time significantly

Comment: there is no need in `_name`. You can do it like this     `var name: String {
        guard let x = x, let y = y else { return "dummy" }
        return x + y
    }`

Comment: @Silmaril OP wants an optional "name" value that *can* be specified, plus two levels of fallbacks if not

Comment: @DeepakSharma what you asking for is to *compute* some result based on the three stored properties in your struct. It is possible to keep `name` as a stored property and possibly update it whenever `X` and `Y` are set using property observers. But that is more complex.

Comment: It's not *simple*. `name` is non-optional, `_name` is optional. How to you set `nil` to `_name`.

Comment: @vadian based on OP’s wording *“if it is not set”*, it sounds like once name receives a value, it will not be “unset”. Allowing setting and unsetting cannot be done using computed properties, it requires a dedicated setter method.

Comment: @Silmaril that will return `x + y` even if `_name` has a value.

Comment: sorry, I also noticed it and deleted. how about this: `    private var _name: String?
    var name: String {
        get {
            guard let name = _name else {
                guard let x = x, let y = y else {
                    return "dummy"
                }
                return x + y
            }
            return name
        }
        set {
            _name = newValue
        }
    }
`

Comment: @Silmaril i think that works, just using `guard let`s instead of `if let`s

Comment: Let's simplify the problem. Let me say there is no "dummy". So name is an optional string that returns X+Y if not set. How do I achieve this?

Comment: @DeepakSharma if `name` is an optional that is not set, accessing `name` directly will return `nil`, as any optional should

Comment: Can you please post the code that doesn't require _name?